# Recommendations For Learning SendMail ASAP?

Tags: sendmail

I'd like to master SendMail operations as quickly (and cost-effectively) as possible.  Are there any books or online course that could help here?

Comment: If you are in a rush, why choose sendmail?  There are lots of good alternatives with a much lower learning curve.

Comment: I am extremely fond of [Safari Books Online](http://ads.stackoverflow.com/a.aspx?Task=Click&ZoneID=6&CampaignID=1352&AdvertiserID=168&BannerID=2175&SiteID=2&RandomNumber=1476273066&Keywords=sendmail%2clearning%2ceducation%2crecommendations%2cx-user-registered%2cx-200plus-rep) for this sort of thing: it is my secret weapon for "learn *X* overnight" missions.  At minimum, you can read/search/use the book that you need and then cancel before the trial is up, but... I sure didn't cancel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best bet would be the [Bat Book](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596510299/), I guess. Not that I speak from experience, as I haven't yet fully recovered from the shock I got when first opening a sendmail.cf somewhere in the darkest 90ies.

Comment: +1. You mean to tell me I need to use `m4` to *process* this config into a "useable" format? :)